# Как нормально реализовать кнопки в допольнительном окне GUI tkinter python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытался найти информация об этом в гугле и ютубе, но ничего толкового не нашел, проблема в чем? Проблема в том что я пытаюсь создать новое окно, с кнопкой, однако когда я нажимаю на первую кнопку в материнском окне, исполняется то что, должно было произойти когда я нажму вторую кнопку во втором окне.

```
from tkinter import messagebox
def new_window():
    window2 = Toplevel()
    btn2 = Button (window2, text = 'test2', command = messagebox.showinfo('Ok.')).pack()
window = Tk()
btn = Button(text = 'test', command = new_window).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Вот зачем вы это делаете? Python это интерпретируемый северный язык. Но есть отдельная группа людей, которая делает на нём графические интерфейсы, игры и компилирует его. А потом появляются вопросы по типу ПАМААГИТЕ!! У меня окно не открывается и python не компилируется!

Answer (score 1):

потому что `messagebox.showinfo('Ok.')` уже вызов функции, а не назначение

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Toplevel, messagebox

def mymsg() :
    messagebox.showinfo('Ok.')

def new_window():
    window2 = Toplevel()
    btn2 = Button(window2, text = 'test2', command = mymsg).pack()
window = Tk()
btn = Button(window, text = 'test', command = new_window).pack()
window.mainloop()
```